# Addition, Subtraction and Division simultaneously on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, division, addition

I have this text box:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Enter Sum of Cleared</label>
  <input type="text" name="sum_cleared" id="sum_cleared" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

I want to divide sum_cleared by 0.85 then multiply the result by 0.94 and subtract it from the original value that is typed in sum_cleared and show the final result in:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Sum of Total</label>
  <input type="text" name="sum_total" id="sum_total" class="form-control total" readonly/>
</div>
```

I want to do this dynamically using the onchange and oninput events so it updates the value of sum_total as the user types the value on sum_cleared.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thank you so much

Comment: What code have you tried? You already said you want to do it in the onchange or oninput events (hint: onchange will wait until the box is unfocused before firing; oninput will fire with every change of input right away). Division uses the operator `/`, multiplication uses the operator `*`, subtraction uses the operator `-`, and all math can be grouped by parentheses (round brackets, like what this is in) to specify what gets evaluated first.

Comment: `sum_cleared - (sum_cleared / 0.85) * 0.94`?

Comment: To the down voter: Rather than immediately down voting, note that this is a brand new Stack Overflow user, and perhaps just post a comment on what you take issue with.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk I was able to do it following the operators you mentioned, please see my answer! Thank you so much

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for the support, I wish I wouldn't have been down voted so fast without getting any input :( I was able to figure out the answer, I just posted it

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do it doing the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter Sum of Cleared</label>
    <input type="text" name="sum_cleared" id="sum_cleared"
           class="form-control"
           oninput="GetTotal(this.value)" onchange="GetTotal(this.value)"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Total Commission</label>
    <input type="text" name="sum_total" id="sum_total"
           class="form-control total" readonly/>
</div>
```

Then adding a small script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetTotal(valNum) {
    document.getElementById("sum_total").value=valNum/0.85*0.94-valNum
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#sum_cleared');
const output = document.querySelector('#sum_total');


input.addEventListener('input', update);
input.addEventListener('change', update);

function update() {
   const updated = input.value - ((input.value / 0.85) * 0.94);
   output.value = updated;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Enter Sum of Cleared</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sum_cleared" id="sum_cleared" class="form-control" />
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Sum of Total</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sum_total" id="sum_total" class="form-control total" readonly/>
                </div>
```